# Transfer a List into a Java Stream,and then delete a element of the List.Some errors occur

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList(){{add("apple");add("banana");add("orange");}};
Stream<String> stringStream = list.stream();
stringStream.forEach(
        m->{
            if (m.equals("banana")){
                list.remove("banana");
            }
        }
);
System.out.println(stringStream.count());
```

Fianlly, the console prints a `NullPointerException` error. The CoreJava says that we shouldn't modify the Collection which will return back to the stream after modified. And I don't have a clear understanding of the principle.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `{{}}` initialization hack when you can use `Arrays.asList`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Consumer` passed to `forEach` must be non-interfering. The reasoning is explained below.

> Non-interference
>
> Streams enable you to execute possibly-parallel aggregate operations over a variety of data sources, including even non-thread-safe collections such as ArrayList. This is possible only if we can prevent interference with the data source during the execution of a stream pipeline. Except for the escape-hatch operations iterator() and spliterator(), execution begins when the terminal operation is invoked, and ends when the terminal operation completes. **For most data sources, preventing interference means ensuring that the data source is not modified at all during the execution of the stream pipeline**. The notable exception to this are streams whose sources are concurrent collections, which are specifically designed to handle concurrent modification. Concurrent stream sources are those whose Spliterator reports the CONCURRENT characteristic.

([Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference))

BTW, your `stringStream.count()` would have failed even if the previous `stringStream.forEach()` statement did not, since `forEach` (as any terminal operation) consumes the `Stream`, and a `Stream` cannot be consumed twice.

The correct way to achieve what you were trying to do is to filter the original `List` and create a new `List`:

```
List<String> filtered = 
    list.stream()
        .filter(m->!m.equals("banana"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: List<String> list = new ArrayList(){{add("apple");add("banana");add("orange");}};
        Stream<String> stringStream = list.stream();
        list.add("pear");
        System.out.println(stringStream.count());      //The answer is 4,correctly.But as the  Non-interference said,we shouldn't operate in this way?

Comment: @jfhuang actually, the example of your comment has no interference, since you mutate the source of the Stream before executing the terminal operation (`count()`). That's why it works. There's actually a comment about that following the paragraph I quoted from the Javadoc : `For well-behaved stream sources, the source can be modified before the terminal operation commences and those modifications will be reflected in the covered elements.`

Answer (score 2):

You can't use streams to remove elements from a list, but you can use lambda expression by calling [`removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-).

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("apple", "banana", "orange"));

list.removeIf(m -> m.equals("banana")); // or: list.removeIf("banana"::equals)

System.out.println(list); // prints: [apple, orange]
System.out.println(list.size()); // prints: 2
```

Comment: Or just `list.remove("banana");`

Comment: @Holger Well, yeah, in this particular case, but this was to show how you can use a condition in a lambda expression to decide whether to remove an element. What the condition is, is not important.

Answer (score -1):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>() 
  {
   {
      add("apple");add("banana");add("orange");
   }
  };

Stream<String> stringStream = list.stream();

final long counter = stringStream.filter(Predicate.not("banana"::equals))
        .count();
System.out.println(counter);
```

Comment: `Predicate.not` is only abvailable in Java 11+. That should probably be pointed out as the question is tagged with `java-8`. In addition, you are not removing bananas from the list.

Comment: Fine, then replace cont() with *Collectors.toList()* and you have a new list without banana. Yes  the original one not modified